# Present perfect simple for an unfinished action

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, progressive-aspect

> I decided to walk back home. I **had walked** for about 200 meters when the storm began and I ran to the nearest cafe.

Would it be possible to use past perfect progressive since the walk was not completed?

[A worksheet about this issue](https://www.eslprintables.com/grammar_worksheets/verbs/verb_tenses/past_perfect_continuous_progressive/PAST_TENSES_PAST_SIMPLE_PAST__493311/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what you have in your example is the past perfect (I had walked) not the present perfect (I have walked).

That said, **yes**, in this case, the past perfect progressive conveys basically the same meaning, and is arguably preferable.

> I had been walking about 200 meters...

One small nuance is that in this *particular* case, the past perfect allows for the possibility that the speaker *stopped* walking after 200 meters, whereas the past perfect progressive sounds like they were walking at the moment the storm hit.

Comment: No, past perfect continuous implies that the action is finished. It's just the aspect of continuity that makes them different. Past simple continuous *was walking* is un unfinished action.

Comment: This is correct: I ***had been walking*** when the storm began. It tells you what the speaker was doing until the moment the storm began. There is no nuance. I ***had been reading*** other questions on this forum when I ***saw*** this one.** But I had walked is also OK.

Comment: @Lambie - Those don't contain the specifier "200 meters", nor do they use the same verb, so their implication sounds different (to me, anyway).

Comment: @LucianSava - It doesn't exactly. Well, it implies that "walking 200 meters" is finished, but not "walking." For instance, "Yesterday I walked a kilometer. I had been walking (or had walked) 200 meters when the storm hit." The action clearly continued after the storm hit.

Answer (score 0):

I was taught that the past perfect simple is used for an amount = 200 meters and the progressive for any length of time = for 20 minutes, for example. So if he had been walking for 20 minutes when the storm began, the past perfect progressive would be correct.

Comment: length and time are not relevant here. How odd that someone would teach you that.  What is relevant is that something had been occurring until something else occurred.

Comment: I disagree, 200 meters is a finished distance, not a duration.

Comment: finished distance is irrelevant: I'd been running five miles for ten years. I had run five miles for ten years. It all depends on the emphasis you want.

Answer (score 0):

- I had been walking for 30 minutes when the storm began.

**The emphasis is on the activity of walking.** One would expect to see something like: **And that's why I was so tired.**

- I had walked for 30 minutes when the storm began.

**The emphasis is on the 30 minutes of time prior to the storm**. One would expect something like: **And that's the actual time I spent walking as I did look at my watch.**

Please note: in both cases, all this is in the past.

Comment: So in my example where is the emphasis, it is not very clear, it could  be the continuity of the activity or  on the 200 meters : so both solutions are ok

Comment: Either is OK, neither though is about completion. One emphasize the activity up to a past point in time; the other the time period prior to a specific point in time. Please forget about finished action here. These actions all occur prior to a point in the past. The point is priority in these sense of coming before...:)

Comment: Would it be the same for this sentence   the plane had flown 30 minutes before he crashed the emphasize is here on the 30 minutes

Comment: @user5577 Yes, you got it.